# my links are not redirecting properly

Tags: php

after running a search in my database the results show up in form of a link so that they redirect me to a particular page...for example when i search for a category business it shows that category but when i click on it it redirects me to the contents of another category..when i checked my url and i noticed its like

```
http://mysite/forum%20part%20two/view_category.php?cid=1
```

instead of

```
http://mysite/forum%20part%20two/view_category.php?cid=2
```

this my search code

```
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){ //form submitted, clicked Submit Search 
    $query = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query'])); //try to prevent sql injections
    if(!$query){ //not enterered a query 
        echo 'You must enter a search query!'; 
    }else{ 
        //EDIT THIS ---------------------------------- 
        $table = 'categories'; //the table you want to search 
        $row = 'category_title'; //the row in which you want to search 
        //EDIT THIS ---------------------------------- 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."` WHERE `".$row."` LIKE '%".$query."%'"); //search query 
        if($sql){ //no errors 
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){ //No results found. 
                echo 'No results were found for <strong>'.$query.'</strong>'; 
            }else{ //one or more results have been found 
                echo 'We have found <strong>'.mysql_num_rows($sql).'</strong> for <strong>'.$query.'</strong>.<br><br> 
                <table> 
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr> 

                            <td><strong>category_title</strong></td> 
                        </tr>'; 
                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ //get data of every user where their category_title is like the $query string 

                    $category_title = $r["category_title"]; 
                    //lets put the part they searched in bold. 
                    $category_title = str_ireplace($query, '<strong>'.$query.'</strong>', $category_title); 
                    //lets put the part they searched in bold. 
                    echo '<td>'.$category_title."<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$category_title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a></td> 
                </tr>'"; 
                } 
                echo '</tbody></table>'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            echo 'Sorry, an MySQL error occurred:<br><br>'.mysql_error(); //an error occurred, so echo it 
        } 
    } 
}
```

my view_category.php code is this

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
include_once("connect.php");

// Function that will count how many replies each topic has
function topic_replies($cid, $tid) {
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) AS topic_replies FROM posts WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $row['topic_replies'] - 1;
}
// Function that will convert a user id into their username
function getusername($uid) {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $row['username'];
}
// Function that will convert the datetime string from the database into a user-friendly format
function convertdate($date) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    return date("M j, Y g:ia", $date);
}

// Assign local variables
$cid = $_GET['cid'];

// Check to see if the person accessing this page is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $logged = " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click Here To Create A Topic</a>";
} else {
    $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum.";
}
// Query that checks to see if the category specified in the $cid variable actually exists in the database
$sql = "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
// Execute the SELECT query
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
// Check if the category exists
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    // Select the topics that are associated with this category id and order by the topic_reply_date
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC";
    // Execute the SELECT query
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
    // Check to see if there are topics in the category
    if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) {
        // Appending table data to the $topics variable for output on the page
        $topics = "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><a href='index.php'>Return To Forum Index</a>".$logged."<hr /></td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr style='background-color: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Last User</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' align='center'>Views</td></tr>";
        $topic = "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
        // Fetching topic data from the database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
            // Assign local variables from the database data
            $tid = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['topic_title'];
            $views = $row['topic_views'];
            $date = $row['topic_date'];
            $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
            // Check to see if the topic has every been replied to
            if ($row['topic_last_user'] == "") { $last_user = "N/A"; } else { $last_user = getusername($row['topic_last_user']); }
            // Append the actual topic data to the $topics variable
            $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted by: ".getusername($creator)." on ".convertdate($date)."</span></td><td align='center'>".$last_user."</td><td align='center'>".topic_replies($cid, $tid)."</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
            $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='4'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
        $topics .= "</table>";
        // Displaying the $topics variable on the page
        echo $topics;
    } else {
        // If there are no topics
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Return To Forum Index</a><hr />";
        echo "<p>There are no topics in this category yet.".$logged."</p>";
    }
} else {
    // If the category does not exist
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Return To Forum Index</a><hr />";
    echo "<p>You are trying to view a category that does not exist yet.";
}
?>
```

sorry for pasting alot of code

Comment: @diEcho sorry i just do not know where im making a mistake

Comment: If you seems %20 in URL is the problem then try running in different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            echo '<td>'.$category_title."<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$category_title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a></td> 
        </tr>'";
```

That variable $id is not being obtained from anywhere, thats probably why. Please fetch its value from your query result near this

```
 $category_title = $r["category_title"];
```

Probably id would be

```
 $id = $r["id"];
```

Comment: yes then you have to check your database for field name for your "id". we cant tell it from here

Comment: from your other file it appears like the field name is "id". So i have updated my suggestion. try that